Is the deep set operation just elementwise addition?
I have been reading the Deep Sets, 2017, Zaheer et al
which has a fair bit of complex looking math.
But I look in the code repo.
and it seems like it is just elementwise addition?
Which is fine and reasonable -- the simplest thing that works.
But I wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding, since the paper seems so complex

Correct.
quoting from the paper section 3.1
The Invarient model  is:


Each instance $x_m$ is transformed (possibly by several layers) into some representation $φ(x_m)$.
The representations $φ(x_m)$ are added up and the output is processed using the $ρ$ network in the
same manner as in any deep network


Their equivarient model is more complex, but if your output is not itself a set then you do not need the equivarient model.
The virtue of the paper comes from showing this simple method works well in practice.
